# Excel: When Dragging formula down, locking the row number and have columns move

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been testing formulas and they have not been working.

The situation: When Dragging formula down, locking the row number and have columns move across on the next tab so stay on row 81 but move from A81 to J81. I am on my 2 tab and need to grab information from first tab. The row needs to be locked and when I drag down, row stays and the next column is selected. I added a picture.

Ie. I select A1 when I go down I want to select B1 and so on.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are asking but if you want to fix the row but not the column make sure $ is only present before the row part e.g. A$1 will fix row 1 but allow column to change.